# Virusscanner removes devtools package with trojan warning?

Tags: r, devtools, antivirus, trojan

I am trying to install the devtools package with `install.packages("devtools")`:

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/RenR/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) also installing the dependencies ‘httr’,
>   ‘rstudioapi’, ‘withr’
>
> There are binary versions available but the source versions are
>   later:
>              binary source needs_compilation httr        1.2.1  1.3.1             FALSE rstudioapi    0.6    0.7             FALSE withr       1.0.2 
>   2.0.0             FALSE devtools   1.12.0 1.13.3              TRUE
>
> Binaries will be installed trying URL
>   'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/devtools_1.12.0.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 432097 bytes (421 KB) downloaded
>   421 KB

However, after downloading and unpacking, my internetsecurity takes over and removes `devtools.dll`. The report I get is (translated):

> Harmful file "devtools.dll" removed
>   Cause: Trojan.RansomKD.12238347, location C:\Users...

Is it possible that there really is something harmful in devtools, or is my internetsecurity overreacting?!

Comment: quite likely it's signature anti-virus going awry. you can go over to virustotal, submit the ZIP file and let it tell you how many detections there are. odds are there was an overzealous file hash collision in your a/v software.

Comment: Hrm… https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/e4df02c23aa4a60a94f8fa5d3329dd6d4870937e46cf75ba2604900ddd49eec8/detection has a 17/64 detection ratio and it seems to be triggerig on behavioural triggers vs file hash. I am not aware of any issues with this particular binary distribution but see if pulling it directly from CRAN makes a difference.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I have tried it from Rgui (as opposed to Rstudio) using https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/devtools_1.12.0.zip and got exactly the same result.

Comment: If you have Rtools installed, can you try to do an install from source vs binary install and see if you're a/v still complains?